# Using BackFire.js with Chaplin.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, firebase, commonjs, chaplinjs

I want to use Firebase's backfire.js in my chaplin.js application.

Is it possible to use both Chaplin.js Collection and backfire.js Collection?

Maybe extending the Chaplin.js Collection and using the backfire.js Collection as a mixin, something like this?

```
Chaplin = require 'chaplin'
Model = require 'models/base/model'
BackBone = require 'backbone'

module.exports = class Collection extends Chaplin.Collection

   _(@prototype).extend BackBone.FireBase.Collection

model: Model
```

Firebase seems to add itself to the Backbone object, in the above example how I should reference it from my code?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Chaplin, but using `Backbone.Firebase.Collection` as a mixin should work. Does it not?

Comment: Is backfirejs compatible with Commonjs?

Answer (score 1):

[Update]

Backfire's special [Firebase Collection object](https://github.com/firebase/backfire/blob/gh-pages/backbone-firebase.js#L158) makes several references to `Backbone.Collection`, which tripped me up for awhile. I replaced this special object entirely to overwrite these references, but there's probably a much better way that my fragile mind cannot yet handle.

..a gist! https://gist.github.com/dustinlarimer/6800730

[Prev]

One quick observation.. drop the 2nd syllable capitalization on Backbone and Firebase:

`_(@prototype).extend Backbone.Firebase.Collection`

You also shouldn't need to include Backbone:

```
Model = require 'models/base/model'

module.exports = class FirebaseModel extends Model
  _(@prototype).extend Backbone.Firebase.Model

  initialize: ->
    console.log 'init FirebaseModel'
    super
```